# A confused for python decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

deco1:

```
def deco(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        f = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("deco success")
        return f

return wrapper
```

deco2:

```
def deal_exc(func):
    def wrapper(*arg, **kwargs):
        try:
             return func(*arg, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
             print(str(e))

    return wrapper
```

use decos:

```
@deal_exc
@deco
def a_function():
    print(0 / 100)
    raise Exception("666")
```

how to skip `print("deco success")` when i raise an exception and let `deal_exc` decorator deal with the exception?

Comment: Just like that. If `func` throws an exception, `print("deco success")` won't be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put a decorator above a decorator, the upper decorator actually wraps(read calls) the lower decorator & similarly, the lower decorator wraps(read calls) the actual function.

So, you cannot skip the handling unless you remove the decorator.

In case you want the inner decorator(`deco`) to NOT handle some specific scenario, you'll have to apply checks for it. eg:

In the above case, since there is no `try-catch` handling in the inner decorator, the exception thrown by the function will automatically be handled by the outermost decorator(`deal_exc`).

Answer (score 0):

Please update the decorator function as below:

```
def deco(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            f = func(*args, **kwargs)
            print("deco success")
        except:
            return f

return wrapper
```

The try-catch statement may help you to handle the exception as you wanted.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you please extend your answer for fellow programmers to understand; how exactly it helps to solve the problem.

Comment: Sure @NagamaInamdar